# PowerShell Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter returns Set-Partition: The requested access path is already in use. Activity ID {

Tags: powershell, partition

With PowerShell, I want to assign a letter to a letterless partition.

Disk number is 0 (the only one in this system), and when I list partitions I get:

```
Partition  DriveLetter Offset       Size        Type
Number
---------  ----------- ------       ----        ----
1                      1048576      260 MB      System
2                      273678336    16 MB       Reserved
3                C     290455552    930.27 GB   Basic
4                      999155564544 1000 MB     Recovery
```

Then I

```
PS C:\> Set-Partition -DiskNumber 0 -PartitionNumber 4 -NewDriveLetter R
Set-Partition: The requested access path is already in use.
Activity ID: {935b6c28-21b8-402c-ad04-44fb199bf958}
```

How can I assign a letter to Partition 4?

Comment: Try with `Get-Partition -PartitionNumber 4 | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter R`

Comment: Just for information your command works well on my Windows 10. So I think that in your case the partition is really in use and you can't add a letter. Can you try to use this command just after reboot ?

Comment: @JPBlanc After I rebooted computer and it worked. Thank you